# timer not running correctly in table ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a timer in my table which is not running correctly for each rows.what i have tried is

```
 var mycount=[7200,3600]

 **the render method in column** 

  {
    title: 'Time ',
    dataIndex: 'project_time',
    key: 'project_time',
    render: (text, record, index) => <>
    {this.timerInt()}
     </> 
  },

**the method is** 
  timerInt = (record) => {
  return <>
  {mycount.map(item => {
  item--;
  var time=new Date(item * 1000).toISOString().substr(11,8);
  return time;
 })}
</>
```

};
**the output(Error) in the table is**
[image]

how can i solve this problem.

Comment: please provide some sandbox here, it will be easier to reproduce

Comment: you need all the code ?

Comment: minimal to reproduce, this is not minimal reproducible, I'm quite sure